# How to programatically go back in a navigation based application

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have created a navigation based application, so when the user clicks on a button, the page navigates to another page (with a back button on it)

In sencha touch how to programatically, `go back` (to the previous view in the navigation stack), and also erase the values contained in fields (in the previous view).

**Update**

```
Ext.getCmp('mainview').push({

                                                          xtype:'second'

                                                         });
```

In the Main.Js

```
Ext.define("app.view.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
           id:'mainview',
```

Comment: I saw you say `navigation stack`. Do the screens actually get stored in a stack?

Comment: Yes i believe so, I have updated my post. please have a look

Comment: have you tried removing the top object (current page) of the stack `pop` then getting the previous page (that is now on top) `peek` and changing all it's fields to empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go programatically back to the previous view in the navigation stack, you can use the method [`pop()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-method-pop),

```
navigationView.pop();
```

on some button click handler.

To erase the values contained in the fields of the previous view(if it's a `formpanel`), you can use the `reset()` method on `formpanel` like this,

```
Ext.getCmp('formpanel-id').reset();
```

This will reset all the values of your `formpanel`.